# AngularJS - ng-repeat + custom filter performance

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I just tried to make my own custom filter with AngularJS.
Now I realized that if I do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in UserArray|myCustomFilter:filterString:'Paramter'">
 {{user.firstname}}, {{user.surename}}
</div>
```

Angular executes the filter for every user in my UserArray on loading. So when the application starts loading all users, it executes at the beginning the myCustomFilter for all users. So I think if there are thousands of users it will be slow... Is there a better way for doing this? The first thing which came in my mind was something like: "Just execute the filter if I enter something in the input box of the filter, and load everything at the beginning without entering the myCustomFilter"...
But is that even possible?

Comment: I think you should actually see if performance is a problem before actually optimizing for performance. Angular does dirty checking which may not be efficient, but it is reliable.  The performance hit should be imperceptible. One way to improve performance for example, is to add paging (and the limitTo filter) to limit the number of records rendered per page.

Comment: +1 to @pixelbits comment. However, if you find performance a problem, get rid of the filtered data binding (i.e. `|`) in your template, and instead do the filtering in your JS by using a `$watch` with the `$filter` service (i.e. `$filter('myCustomFilter')(UserArray, filterString)`).